# Sent Ether to an ICO from a non ERC-20 compatible wallet

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, erc-20

So, I transferred some ether from my Koinex Wallet(non ERC-20 compatible) to [Bloom ICO](https://contribution.hellobloom.io/#contribute) which clearly expects an ERC-20 compatible wallet. At the time of transaction I had no idea about ERC-20 wallets since I am new to this. After making the transaction I realized the blunder I had made. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Bloom ICO. Even though this question might be specific to a HelloBloom customer service, I'll provide a generic answer here.

Looks like HelloBloom are conducting their ICO in an irresponsible way by accepting payments from all kind of Ethereum wallets. HelloBloom could have easily prevented accidents like this by

1) asking user for their wallet service and letting only whitelisted good known EIP-20 wallets to proceed

2) require high gas amount and Data field to be filled in the payment, as usually exchanges and reduced functionality wallets do not let in you to fill in Data field or specify high gas limit.

[The latter mechanism is described in detail here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/issues/53). It is nothing new as the safety mechanism has existed since FirstBlood and Golem ICOs which where 3rd and 4th Ethereum ICOs in Autumn 2016.

Your options in this point are

- Check your transaction on EtherScan if it went through
- If the transaction went through then contact Koinex customer support and ask them to recover your tokens
- Complain to HelloBloom and tell them that they could have easily prevented this user error and possibly ask them to send extra tokens to a different address in the case Koinex is unwilling to help you

Neither Koinex or HelloBloom may or may not be willing to help you. Usually exchanges do not provide token recovery for small value of tokens. For example, in some point of time for Bittrex the minimum threshold of recovery was 5000 USD and they may have collected an extra recovery fee.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Guess, I'll just drop both of them an email and  hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

I only found this. Made the same mistake. 
Is it an ETH Wallet but don´t support ICO.
I think a lot of people did that mistake.

Here is what you may try to do... Is in Exodus Wallet

http://support.exodus.io/article/128-how-do-i-receive-unsupported-erc20-tokens

Maybe you can try it... I didn´t try it yet.

But I think your tokens don´t go anywhere, one day someone will find a sollution for all those missin coins.